# ICollection filter error convert type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have filter my collection

It is my code

```
 public ICollectionView LogEntriesStoreView { get; set; }

  var collection = new ObservableCollection<Service>(this._model.GetService());

   this.LogEntriesStoreView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);

            this.LogEntriesStoreView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyBargainsFilter);


private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            AuctionItem product = e.Item as AuctionItem;
            if (product != null)
            {
                // Filter out products with price 25 or above
                if (product.CurrentPrice < 25)
                {
                    e.Accepted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Accepted = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I get this error 
Implicit type conversion "System.Windows.Data.Filter EventHandler" in "System.Predicate " can not be

```
this._view = new TViewType();
            this._model = new ServiceModel();
            this.Service = new ObservableCollection<Service>(this._model.GetService());
            this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand(o => this.OKRun());
            this.LostFocusCommand = new RelayCommand(o => this.LostFocusOKRun());

            // в переменную получаем нашу коллекцию
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<Service>(this._model.GetService());
            // инициализируем поле типа ICollectionView нашей коллецией
            this.LogEntriesStoreView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);

            this.LogEntriesStoreView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Contains);

            this.LogEntriesStoreView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyBargainsFilter);


            this._view.SetDataContext(this);
            this._view.ShowIView();
        }

        private void OKRun()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("One Click");
        }

        private void LostFocusOKRun()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("LostFocus");
        }

        private void TextChanged()
        {

        }

        private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public bool Contains(object de)
        {

            return true;
        }
```

full code, i added a predicate in me code. All made for example on msdn

Comment: I understand it, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I do everything by example

Comment: There must be some syntax error causing this. can you add the relevant code here.

Comment: Did you followed each step? check whether you have assigned similar to  "myCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Contains);".

Answer (score 0):

EventHandler should work for `CollectionViewSource LogEntriesStoreView`.

There is a difference between implementation of Filter for CollectionView and CollectionViewSource.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx